# DELETE IGNORE on Tables with Foreign Keys Can Break Replication

Tags: mysql, delete-row

> I am using replication in a MYSQL database. I have read some where DELETE IGNORE command on Tables with Foreign Keys can break Replication. Is it true? If it is true then how can workaround this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably read it here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/02/02/stop-delete-ignore-on-tables-with-foreign-keys-can-break-replication/

The details of how DELETE IGNORE can be unsafe for replication is shown in that blog.

The solution to work around the issues to do either one of:

- Don't use `DELETE IGNORE`
- Use Row-Based Replication by setting `binlog-format=ROW`

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I have read there. Is this correct?

Comment: I know the author who wrote that blog, he is one of the best MySQL experts in the world, and he is very diligent about testing his results. I trust that he is correct. If you have any doubt, he describes the steps to reproduce the issue, you can do it yourself.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll consider.